# A constant ratio of integrals? Part I

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $u(x)$ be a harmonic polynomial in the unit ball $B_1(0)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with $u(0)=0$.

For $0<r\leq1$, consider the average of its Dirichlet integral
$$A(r):=\frac1{\vert B_r(0)\vert}\int_{B_r(0)}\vert\nabla u\vert^2dx,$$
and the average of the square function on the boundary
$$B(r):=\frac1{\vert \partial B_r(0)\vert}\int_{\partial B_r(0)}u^2d\sigma.$$

I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is this true? The ratio $\frac{r^2A(r)}{B(r)}$ is a constant in $r$.

Comment: Is $u$ real-valued, or did you mean $|u|^2$ in place of $u^2$?

Comment: Yes, $u$ is real-valued.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. E.g., if $n=2$ and $u(x,y)=x + x^2 - y^2$ for $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$, then $\dfrac{r^2A(r)}{B(r)}=2\dfrac{1+2r^2}{1+r^2}$.

Comment: Ouch! I know what I missed in the assumptions.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan : Despite the simplicity of the example, I spent quite a bit of time to find it. So, It would be great if you would reverse your latest edit.

Comment: Done, Iosif Pinelis, now there is a Part II.

Comment: Why the downvote? Can you explain?