# A constant ratio of integrals? Part II

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

This question is a follow up on my latest [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425179/a-constant-ratio-of-integrals-part-i) which was addressed kindly by Iosif Pinelis. What is new here is that I need to correct the assumption by including a missing hypothesis. The context required me to look into spherical harmonics. That is why.

Let $u(x)$ be a **homogeneous** harmonic polynomial in the unit ball $B_1(0)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with $u(0)=0$.

For $0<r\leq1$, consider the average of its Dirichlet integral
$$A(r):=\frac1{\vert B_r(0)\vert}\int_{B_r(0)}\vert\nabla u\vert^2dx,$$
and the average of the square function on the boundary
$$B(r):=\frac1{\vert \partial B_r(0)\vert}\int_{\partial B_r(0)}u^2d\sigma.$$

I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is this true? The ratio $\frac{r^2A(r)}{B(r)}$ is a constant in $r$.

Comment: Yes, using that $|\nabla u|^2 = \text{div}(u\nabla u)$, integrating by parts, and using that $u_r = k r^{-1}u$ where $k$ is the degree of the polynomial, one sees that $r^2A(r) = nkB(r)$. This is an instance of the Almgren monotonicity formula, which says that $r^2A/B$ is non-decreasing in $r$, and constant if and only if $u$ is homogeneous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, this is true for any homogeneous polynomial $u$ (not identically $0$), be $u$ harmonic or not.

Indeed, let $m\ge1$ be the degree of such a polynomial $u$. Then
$$u(tx)=t^m u(x)$$
and
$$v(tx)=t^{2m-2} v(x)$$
for all real $t$, where $v:=|\nabla u|^2$. So, for $B_r:=B_r(0)$,
$$\int_{B_r}v(x)\,dx =\int_{B_1}v(ry)\,r^n\,dy =
r^{2m-2+n}\int_{B_1}v(y)\,dy,$$
whence
$$A(r)=a_{n,u}r^{2m-2},$$
where $a_{n,u}$ is a nonnegative real constant depending only on $n$ and $u$.

Similarly,
$$B(r)=b_{n,u}r^{2m},$$
where $b_{n,u}$ is a positive real constant depending only on $n$ and $u$.

Now the desired result immediately follows.